# System of Nonlinear Equations (sum of powers)

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I want to show the only solution to the following system of equations is the trivial one ($x_{i} = 0$). I don't know if this is true, but I think it should be.

Let $x_{i} \in \mathbb{C}$ for $1 \le i \le n$

$$x_{1}+\ldots+x_{n} = 0 \\
x_{1}^{2}+\ldots+x_{n}^{2}=0 \\
\ldots \\
x_{1}^{n}+ \ldots+x_{n}^{n}=0$$

I worked out the case for $n=2$ and $3$, with basic algebraic manipulation but I can't see a way to more systematically show $x_{i} = 0$ for $\forall i$ for an arbitrary $n$. It seems there should be a neat manipulation to make this work out, or perhaps not. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Could this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @Chip Thanks, that's very helpful, the Vandermonde matrix appears to be precisely what's above (minus the condition that each row is equal to $0$). The Vandermonde determinant seems like it would be useful in this case, but it seems the information it provides is rather limited (nonzero determinant if all $x_{i}$ are distinct).

Comment: Assume that $x_i$ are the roots of a polynomial equation of order $n$ ($x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+..+a_0=0$) and use Vieta formulas to find the coefficients of the polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas. This means we need to find the sum of the roots (your first equation), the sum of paired products (this one relates easily to your second equations), and so onward...Ideally, you could prove that all the polynomial coefficients (related by Vieta relations to the sum of products of the roots) are null. Hence, you get $x^n=0$, thus all your solutions are zero.